# SSRS Colour Fomatting across multiple columns

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I've created a SSRS report to examine whether certain fields contain a specific value using a simple case, when statement with the values returned being 'Yes' or 'No'. I'd like the cells to be coloured yellow with the value is a 'Yes'. (See [Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubtrN.png)).

I know I can do this using the function IIF(Fields!Result1.Value="Yes","Yellow","Transparent") but for a table with multiple columns (>60), is there a way to copy the background colour formatting without having to write the function for each column?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the value of each text box/cell with "YES" then you can use the **`ME.Value`** reference.
There is little documentation on ME (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255285.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
=IIF(ME.Value = "Yes", "Yellow", "Transparent")
```

> To access the value of the current text box, you can use the Visual
>   Basic built-in global Me.Value or simply Value. In report functions
>   such as First and aggregate functions, use the fully qualified syntax.

Unfortunately, ME does not seem to be fully implemented - it causes errors when used in places that were not created to use ME correctly. An **ACTION** (i.e. Go To URL) that uses ME will fail with an error of an unknown reference.

Comment: This is perfect! I was able to set this as the fill across all columns in my worksheet!! Thank you very much!